# Jquery Function object

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $JTj(document).ready(function() {   
        var map = {"rows": 4, "cols" : 4};
        alert(map.rows);
        formUpdate(map);    
    });

    function formUpdate(map) {
       if (map != undefined) {
           $JTj('#mapContainer').selectionmap(map);
       }
    }
   formUpdate(map); 
</script>
```

// Simple Library

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($JTj) {
    $JTj.fn.selectionmap = function (options) {
        alert(options.rows);
    };
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I am getting error,

> ReferenceError: `$JTj` is not defined `$JTj(document).ready(function() {`

please lets me know what are the changes should be done.

Comment: Why are you trying to rename the jQuery object to $JTj?

Comment: i didn't get, can please explain little more.

Answer (score 2):

In your current code, `$JTj` is only accessible in the scope of your self-invoking anonymous function.

You would have to wrap your first code snippet in another (or maybe the same) anonymous function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    (function($JTj) {
        $JTj(document).ready(function() {   
            var map = {"rows": 4, "cols" : 4};
            alert(map.rows);
            formUpdate(map);    
        });

        function formUpdate(map) {
           if (map != undefined) {
               $JTj('#mapContainer').selectionmap(map);
           }
        }
        formUpdate(map); 
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

In passing, be careful: you're issuing a call to `formUpdate()` outside of a `ready` handler. The DOM may not be ready yet when that call is performed.

Comment: You should not use `(document).ready(function() ` with jQuery Mobile. Instead must use `pageshow`, `pagecreate` events. please find the documentation http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/ please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Mayu, that would be the [pageinit](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html) event. You're right in the general case, but I'm not sure the questioner's markup actually implements jQuery Mobile pages. If it does, he definitely should follow your advice.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi cool thanks for the kind reply. yeap it should be pageinit